# PyDev + mpi4py -> run through shellscript / mpirun

Tags: python, mpi, pydev

I'd like to create python programs that use `mpi4py` and thus I'd like to run them using the following command:

```
mpirun -np 4 python script.py
```

I tried to create a shell script which does this and use it as a python interpreter but eclipse rejects the shell script. I tried to redirect the output (so that it doesen't show the mpi-stuff but soley prints the python-output of the first node).

If I run the script in the console using the `interpreterinfo.py` script to test the interpreter it gives exactly the same output as if I run it only through python.

It somehow seems that the script isn't executed properly by eclipse or that the output is not going into stdout.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should try to configure mpirun as the python interpreter... Instead, configure the python interpreter as usual and just create a python module that'll do the launching for you and launch that module instead... (or create an external launch in run > external tools)

It'd be strange that mpirun is the actual python interpreter, because that way when requesting a code completion for builtins, pydev would launch the mpirun and it'd create 4 processes for code-completion? The same would apply to other things such as debug, coverage, etc...

Comment: It's not that this actually is "the solution" but I see why I shouldn't use mpirun as interpreter. Thank you for the explanation. For me this question is solved.